# Generating Haxe externs for EaselJS

Tags: javascript, haxe, easeljs

Being new to both JavaScript and Haxe, this may have a simple answer, but I've discovered that Haxe has externs port on GoogleCode for EaselJS, but they are out of date and correspond to an earlier version.  I've been able to fix errors as they occur during compile time, but I'm still wary that I didn't catch al the new variables and function names.

My question is: is there a simple way to generate externs for a large JS library like EaselJS?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Joshua Granick's work with BuildJS:

http://www.joshuagranick.com/blog/2011/10/14/use-buildjs-to-make-externs-for-haxe-js-automatically/

Basically there's a tool called JSDuck which is supposed to compile documentation for JavaScript libraries, and it can output to JSON.  He's used the output from JSON, combined with his "buildjs" library to build haxe externs.

He's used it for Sencha Touch, and I've used it for ExtJS, but both of those are Sencha products and their coding style is known to work with JSDuck.  You can give it a go with EaselJS, if it works then BuildJS should generate pretty accurate externs.

Otherwise, you might try find the author of the original EaselJS externs and see if they can provide an update, or give you help creating an accurate update.  Most of the haxe developers you can contact easily enough using the mailing list or google groups:

http://groups.google.com/group/haxelang?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late with the answer but you can find the latest (v0.5.0) externs for EaselJs here:

https://github.com/Fintan/easelhx

I generated them using BuildHx (https://github.com/jgranick/buildhx) which is now able to parse YUIDoc comments and then tested them by porting some of the code samples that accompany the EaselJs source.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I did try and install Joshua's tool, but I'm running into an issue with JSDuck.

In the example you linked to, JSDuck is supposed to have a --json param, but the latest version seems to have deprecated that.  I'm trying some others using the config file:

```
{    
"--out": "out",
"--guides": "json",
"--warnings": ["all"],
"--": [
    "src/easeljs/"
]}
```

But that doesn't work.  The guides param seems to fail no matter what I try.

Creating the json file gives me this ouput:

```
C:/Users/mycmp/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr374A.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jsduck-3.3.0/lib/jsduck/json_duck.rb:36:in `read': Permission denied - K:/Vault/Haxe/myproj/json (Errno::EACCES)
```

So I'm not sure what to do next.  It'd be great to get this working for lots of libraries.

By the way, I'm using the latest JSDuck and Windows 7.

Comment: Instead of `--json` (which has been removed) use `--export=full`. The `--guides` parameter has nothing to do with export. Run `jsduck --help=full` for overview of all options.